# Создание профилей для пользователей в консольном приложении Java

Tags: java, консоль

Всем привет. Имеется приложение, к нему подключены геттер и сеттер, в данном варианте сохраняет только один профиль пользователя. Тоесть, пользователь в меню выбирает сохранение профиля, он записывается в сеттер и забирается геттером. Нужно сделать, чтоб могли добавиться несколько пользователей и он выводил список этих пользователей с несколькими переменными.

Comment: давайте код, потому что по вашему описанию понятно, только то, что вы недавно прочитали про геттер и сеттер))

Comment: Если геттер и сеттер может принимать несколько значений то задача решится?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас принимает строка то тут понятно почему, каждый раз будет одно и тоже, для решение сделайте массив(лучше динамический через коллекцию List). без кода тяжело понять какая проблема у вас